# MySQL / PHP Create Event Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm getting a 1604 syntax error in my sql query trying to create an event.

The query runs fine in phpmyadmin so I'm not sure what is wrong here.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE EVENT 'exp_$evtname' ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE `members` SET `token` = '' WHERE `memberID` = '$memid'";
```

and the page is giving the error: "

```
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near ''exp_wbjlc' ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR ON COMPLET' at line 1
```

Any insight on what's going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try double quotes on 'ex_$eventname'

Comment: double quotes everywhere do use php variables inside

Comment: @AndreiTodorut changing it to double quotes caused a 500 error.